# Why did Eragon Shadeslayer leave Alagaësia?

Tags: dragons, inheritance-cycle

In Inheritance Eragon Shadeslayer left Alagaësia, convinced that the dragons would never be safe there; he needed to take them elsewhere to be safe. However, after defeating Galbatorix and learning the name for the ancient language (giving him power over all magic), why was he unable to keep the dragons in Alagaësia?

He could have taken them to the Beor Mountains, so high no one could reach from frostbite or suffocation, and casting magic to keep himself and the dragons safe.
Eragon could have gone to the Hadarac, and increased the dangers of the sun for everyone outside a specific oasis.

There were plenty of things he could do to keep the dragons there and still interact with Arya, Roran, and his other friends without jeopardizing the dragons. Why did he have to go? Or, if the dragons were just an excuse, what was the real reason?

*I'm assuming Christopher Paolini dug himself in a corner with the prophecy or he wanted to end the series and couldn't think of a good ending, but I am more interested in the canon, non-authorial reasons*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One factor was the difficulty Eragon would have reconciling his role as the new leader of the Dragon Riders with his sworn loyalty to Nasuada and his deep connections and friendships with the Elves (and Dwarves). He says as much in [Inheritance](https://books.google.com/books?id=fgCnGzN9NakC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inheritance%20leave&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2Zz_VNXoD4WwggTe5IKgAg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAg#v=snippet&q=%22decided%20to%20leave%22&f=false), p. 804-805:

> "Eragon! What are you thinking! You know you have to join. All of the magicians who serve me have to. There can't be any exceptions. Not one! I can't have people think that I'm playing favorites. It would sow dissent among the ranks of the magicians, and that is exactly what I *don't* want. As long as you are a subjeect of my realm, you have to abide by its laws, or my authority means *nothing*. I shouldn't have to tell you that, Eragon."
>
> "You don't. I'm well aware of it, which is why Saphira and I have decided to leave Alagaësia."
>
> ...
>
> "I don't understand."
>
> ...
>
> "It never would have worked for me to take charge of the magicians. Saphira and I have to raise the dragons and train the Riders, and that must take precedence before all else. Even if I had the time, I couldn't lead the Riders and still answer to you - the other races would never stand for it. Despite Arya's choice to become queen, the Riders have to remain as impartial as possible. If *we* start to play favorites, it will destroy Alagaësia. The only way I would consider accepting the position would be if the magicians were to include those of every race - even the Urgals - but that's not likely to happen. Besides, it would still leave the question of what to do about the eggs and the Eldunarí."

In the same passage, Eragon also lists several other logistical factors for leaving:

- The need for physical barriers to defend the Dragons, most importantly the distance
- The need to keep the Dragons fed with livestock other than that from farms and Dwarven hunt animals

But then Eragon reveals the most important reason for leaving, somewhat similar to the first reason I mentioned, but with a twist - it wouldn't be *right for him to stay*, but not because of the loyalty issues. As he says:

> "I've become *too* powerful. As long as I'm here, your authority - and that of Arya, Orik, and Orrin - will always be in doubt. If I asked them to, most everyone in Surda, Teirm, and your own kingdom would follow me. And with the Eldunarí to help me, there is no one who can stand against me, not even Murtagh or Arya."
>
> "...because I have this power at my disposal, I have a responsibility to act...If I was wrong, though, who could stop me? I could end up becoming Galbatorix, despite my best intentions...My presence here unbalances things, Nasuada. If I am to avoid becoming what I hate, then I have to leave."

**TL;DR:** It wasn't just fear for the dragon's safety, it was the need to let the lands be free from his influence, to not be ruled by another Rider King. The fact that there were logistical, safety, and loyalty questions as well were just icing on the cake.

Answer (score 1):

In book one Angela cast Eragon fortune which foretold that he would leave Alagesia and never return. Additionally, Eragon didn't want to rule Alagaesia because he believed it would do more harm than good if another rider would assume the throne.  He would be busy raising the next generation of dragon riders when the eggs he found on Vroengard  hatch to deal with imperial duties. He also needed to find a safe place for the Eldunari he freed from Galbatorix to recover. Ultimately he left to protect the dragons and Eldunari so no one could threaten or abuse them again.

Answer (score 1):

Also, as Saphira says somewhere (Sorry for being vague, not on purpose), she wouldn't really enjoy the living in the Beor mountains, even if there WAS a lot of flying area. Also, that brought the dragons into contact with the dwarves Feldunost flocks. Plus, it's not really difficult for a reasonably talented magician to be able to survive at the altitudes of the Beor mountains.

Also, if Eragon, in the first book, being as powerful (In the sense, as weak as he was) as he was, could easily (well, not EASILY) cross the Hadarac, there might be others willing to risk more to get to the centre.

The most compelling reason though is that dragons, by definItion, CANNOT be contained. You cannot restrict their range. Its just not in their nature.

Alagaesia was a crowded place. Humans everywhere. Non-magical ones.

Thus, the dragons, along with Eragon HAD to leave.

Plus, it also helps that there's a prophecy made all the way back in the first book.

Answer (score 1):

Eragon probably left for the better of the dragons, humans, and every other race in Alegesia because of all his power.  It was also probably hard for him to give up almost everything he loved, but he did it anyway. That is an admirable attribute of Eragon's personality.

Comment: This seems like some nice reasoning but it could probably do with some evidence [edit]ing in such as quotes. i.e. why would it be better if he left because of his power? Are there any quotes indicating that he did leave because of his power etc.